# Ternary operator applied to different lambdas produces inconsistent results

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++20, noexcept

Consider the following which uses the ternary operator to get the common function pointer type of the two lambdas

```
int main() {
  true ? [](auto) noexcept {} : [](int) {};
}
```

GCC-trunk only accepts it in C++14 but rejects it in C++17/20 with ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7r4dKbo73)):

```
<source>:2:8: error: operands to '?:' have different types 'main()::<lambda(auto:1)>' and 'main()::<lambda(int)>'
    2 |   true ? [](auto) noexcept {} : [](int) {};
      |   ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Clang-trunk accepts it in all C++14/17/20 mode ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/49c6qseYq)).

MSVC-trunk only accepts it in C++20 but rejects it in C++14/17 with ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6efejoeTY)):

```
<source>(2): error C2446: ':': no conversion from 'main::<lambda_01e5bb79b5a210014fb78333f6af80f9>' to 'main::<lambda_57cf6f5767bc1bee4c1e1d9859a585d2>'
<source>(2): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Which compiler is right?

Comment: Both results type of a conditional expression must be either of the same type, or of types that can be implicitly convertible between each other.  Each lambda is a unique type, and can't be converted to another lambda.

Comment: "*Each lambda is a unique type, and can't be converted to another lambda.*" No, both `[]{}` and `[]{}` can be converted to `void (*)()`.

Comment: While that's true, that involves *two* conversions. Generally speaking, and very simplistic, anything that takes more than one conversion is invalid.

Comment: How is `auto` deduced in this example, oh wise ones?

Comment: MSVC's legacy lambda parser is very buggy. The new parser (needs `/Zc:lambda` in C++14/17 modes) behaves correctly ([Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/1sj5Tab7e)).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since each lambda expression has a unique type, and neither lambda expression is convertible to the other, [[expr.cond]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#6) applies.

> If the second and third operands do not have the same type, and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type, overload resolution is used to determine the conversions (if any) to be applied to the operands ([over.match.oper], [over.built]). If the overload resolution fails, the program is ill-formed.
> Otherwise, the conversions thus determined are applied, and the converted operands are used in place of the original operands for the remainder of this subclause.

The candidates are ([[over.built]/25](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#25)):

> For every type `T`, where `T` is a pointer, pointer-to-member, or scoped enumeration type, there exist candidate operator functions of the form
>
> ```
> T       operator?:(bool, T, T);
> ```

I believe that overload resolution should succeed in this case, and as a result, both operands should be converted to `void(*)(int)`.

That is, IMO clang is correct.

---

Edit: I believe that `[](auto) noexcept {}` is convertible to `void(*)(int)`, because it has a conversion function template `template<class T> operator FP()`, where `FP` is `void(*)(T)` ([[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.closure#9)).

> For a generic lambda with no lambda-capture, the closure type has a conversion function template to pointer to function.
> The conversion function template has the same invented template parameter list, and the pointer to function has the same parameter types, as the function call operator template.
> The return type of the pointer to function shall behave as if it were a decltype-specifier denoting the return type of the corresponding function call operator template specialization.

And I believe that template argument deduction should make this conversion template usable as a conversion to `void(*)(int)` ([[temp.deduct.conv]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.conv#5)).

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing the return type of the conversion function template (call it `P`) with the type specified by the *conversion-type-id* of the *conversion-function-id* being looked up (call it `A`) as described in [temp.deduct.type].
>
> [...]
>
> In general, the deduction process attempts to find template argument values that will make the deduced `A` identical to `A`.
> However, certain attributes of `A` may be ignored:
>
> - [...]
> - If the original `A` is a function pointer or pointer-to-member-function type, its `noexcept`.

Comment: I can't catch the point where we are allowed to use a template lambda with auto conversion to some pointer type. ( which type it can be?, a template type itself ? ) And if, as you mentioned, we can deduce the template lambda to int... why in overload resolution this should happen... Sorry for uncertainty, but the auto to int deduction looks mystery to me!

Comment: @Klaus me too..

Comment: @Klaus I've edited the answer to cover that part.

Comment: I am with you if we write `void(*ptr)(int) = ...` that the both lambdas can be converted to function pointers of the given type. In the given case gcc complains about the difference of `noexcept` :-) Really strange!

Comment: Puh... I tried out a simplified example: void f1(auto); void f2(int); template < typename T> T magic( bool, T t1,T ){return t1;} auto f = magic( true, f1,f2 ); f(1);` That works in gcc! If the `T       operator?:(bool, T, T);` can be assumed, it should also work for the code of OP! I was not aware of the rule that a fixed parm will result in forcing a template parm to be the same! Thanks! Time to write a bug report for gcc! Will you do it please?

Comment: Filed [PR105221](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105221).