# Can we write a function which returns a function pointer to a function template?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

Is it possible to write a function or method which can return a pointer to a template function or template method?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
struct X1 {
  static void Do(auto n) { std::cout << "1" << n << std::endl; }
  // static auto GetPtr() { return X1::Do; }  // how to write such a function?
};
struct X2 {
  static void Do(int n) { std::cout << "2" << n << std::endl; }
  //static auto  GetPtr(){ return &Do; }
};

template <typename T> T magic(bool b, T t1, T t2) { return b ? t1 : t2; }

int main() {
  auto l1 = magic(true, X1::Do, X2::Do);

  // should be replaced by:
  //   auto l1 = magic( true, X1::GetPtr(), X2::GetPtr() );

  l1(100);
}
```

If I compile the above out-commented functions, I got from gcc:

> main.cpp:1845:39: error: unable to deduce 'auto' from 'X1::Do'

Background: I am currently trying to understand the overload resolution in same cases. In the given case you see that the overload for `int` is taken because one function pointer *only* has an int parameter so the second pointer overload can be found.

I was triggered by that question:  [Ternary operator applied to different lambdas produces inconsistent results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71826315/ternary-operator-applied-to-different-lambdas-produces-inconsistent-results)

Here in an answer was suggested, that a lambda should be able to provide a conversion operator to a function pointer... and I did not see it :-)

Comment: No, because as the correct term (and not the misnomer "template function") implies, a function template is not a function. Templates are not the the same sort of entities as the thing they produce. They are purely compile time factories.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Quite clear, I though of something like a pointer template itself... sometimes we have some magic I am not aware of it :-)

Comment: @MarcusMüller: saw it... also removed :-)

Comment: @Klaus Even if you could do this, `X1::Do(auto ...` would need to take the same type as `X2::Do(int ...`, thas is, `int` or else the conditional operator would be unhappy. If you're fine with that, does [this](https://godbolt.org/z/n9EWYjK3G) work for you?

Comment: @TedLyngmo In comparison to the directly used pointers, your solution needs the "hint" that we want to use `int`. In the given example the  pointer `l1` is automatically using `int` because one of the function pointers is only an ptr to an function which takes int. That is the "tricky" thing I am searching for.

Comment: i dont understand how the last paragraph relates to the posted code, however here you can read about the conversion operator that can cconvert lambdas to function pointers: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda (look for `ClosureType::operator ret(*)(params)()`)

Comment: note that you can get a function pointer from a lambda with `auto` argument, but the function pointer is only to one specific instantiation of the call operator, sloppy speaking the `auto` gets lost once you turn it into a function pointer.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number If you go to the linked question, there is an answer which tells it should be possible to pick the correct overload from different lambdas used in a ternary operator by using the conversion operator which delivers the pointer to the lambda execution operator. *My* understanding is, that is not possible, because we simply can't keep the "auto" type in it. Thats the core of my question here. As an alternative a implementation for the ternary operator must directly access via the <lamda_type>::operator()(parms_types...); It was my intention to reduce my question here...

Comment: Imho you should clarify the quesiton. It seems like the question is about lambdas with `auto` arguments converting to function pointers, but it isnt obvious that the code you posted is meant to illustrate that. Also note that I edit my answer. I am still not sure if I understand what you are looking for but maybe the answer is now slightly more towards what you actually want to ask

Comment: I expected that the simple answer is simply "NO". But I was not sure as sometimes there is something in the big tool box of C++ which I am not aware of. So I simply accept the NO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot return a pointer to a function template, because a function template is not a function. It is a template.

```
// static auto GetPtr() { return X1::Do; }  // how to write such a function?
```

You need `&` to get a pointer to a member function, though `Do` is not a member function it is a member function template. You could return a pointer to `X1::Do<int>` or to `X1::Do<double>` but there is no pointer to `X1::Do`.

You can however return a functor with an overloaded call operator and that operator can be a template:

```
struct foo {
   template <typename T>
   void operator()(const T& t) {}

   void operator()(int x){}
};    

foo magic() { return foo{}; }

int main() {
    magic()(3);                    // calls operator()(int)
    magic()("hello world");        // calls operator()<const char[12]>
}
```

---

After rereading your question and the Q&A you link, I think you are maybe looking for this:

```
#include <iostream>
struct X1 {
  static void Do(auto n) { std::cout << "1" << n << std::endl; }
  static auto GetPtr() { return &X1::Do<int>; }
};
struct X2 {
  static void Do(int n) { std::cout << "2" << n << std::endl; }
  static auto  GetPtr(){ return &Do; }
};

template <typename T> T magic(bool b, T t1, T t2) { return b ? t1 : t2; }

int main() {
  auto l1 = magic( true, X1::GetPtr(), X2::GetPtr() );

  l1(100);
}
```

As stated above, you cannot get a member function pointer to `X1::Do` but you can get a pointer to `X1::Do<int>`.

And as you are refering to conversion of lambdas to function pointers: Also lambdas with `auto` argument can only be converted to function pointers **after** choosing the argument type. Consider the example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> ```
> void f1(int (*)(int)) {}
> void f2(char (*)(int)) {}
> void h(int (*)(int)) {}  // #1
> void h(char (*)(int)) {} // #2
>  
> auto glambda = [](auto a) { return a; };
> f1(glambda); // OK
> f2(glambda); // error: not convertible
> h(glambda);  // OK: calls #1 since #2 is not convertible
>  
> int& (*fpi)(int*) = [](auto* a) -> auto& { return *a; }; // OK
> ```

It is not possible to get a pointer to function of type `auto(auto)` (it isn't a type of a function to begin with). In all the calls above, after the conversion there is no `auto` anymore. Instead the requested type is deduced and a conversion to the respective function pointer is done.

Comment: Thank you, but that did not help for my purpose of overload resolution.

Comment: @Klaus why not ? Then I dont understand the actual issue you are trying to solve

Comment: @Klaus I dont understand what you mean with "my purpose of overload resolution".

Comment: In my above example code the overload resolution finds the overload to `int` *before* we call it with an int. The function pointer generated by `magic` is already to a function which takes an int as parm before we call it with an int. Simply call the function via a proxy did not open the overload resolution if we provide two pointers... here we have simply no pointer...

Comment: @Klaus why is it an issue that there is no pointer? I also realized that the code in my answer is different from yours, because it is only overload resolution that chooses which function to call while in your code the `bool` decides between the `int` and the `auto` function, but that just needs a small modification , also no pointer needed. The point is that you cannot have a pointer to an overload set or to a function template, you can only have a pointer to a single function

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't "know" in advance all your uses for `X1::GetPtr` (generally). It seems you are expecting the compiler to 1. recognize it is a template 2. recognize all uses for the function, and see if it can deduce all instantiations needed for the template "for free", so to speak - in your case only the use in `magic`, but this is not general.

There is no such mechanism in C++ and the compiler must know the type of the function when it parses it, or recognize it as a template (and not guess it).

Simply put, I think you are expecting the compiler to do something too difficult, and it can't. As such, you will have to do the template resolution yourself:

```
template<typename N>
static auto GetPtr() { return &X1::Do<N>; }
```

and call it with

```
magic(true, X1::GetPtr<int>(), X2::GetPtr());
```