# How do I create a function pointer pointing to a templated function

Tags: c++

I need to create a function pointer to a templated function whose return type I know.

The function itself looks like this:

```
    template <typename T>
    void m_print(const T& message) requires std::convertible_to<T, std::wstring>
    {
        std::wcout << message << std::endl;
    }
```

I tried creating the function pointer the standard way and it didn't work. Additionally, I tried looking for a solution on the web but didn't find it

Comment: Not possible since c++ doesn't allow to have a pointer to a "template".

Comment: Then what do I do guys?

Comment: Do you mean `auto f = &m_print<my_type>`?

Comment: There is no such thing as "templated function". There are function templates like `m_print`, which are not functions, and you cannot create pointers to them. Then there are template specializations like `m_print<int>`, which are normal functions, and you can create pointers to them in the normal way: `&m_print<int>`.

Comment: *"The function itself looks like this...."* Note that is not actually a function. [Can we write a function which returns a function pointer to a function template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71829344/can-we-write-a-function-which-returns-a-function-pointer-to-a-function-template)

Comment: what do you want to do with the pointer once you got it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function pointer points to a function. A function template is not a function. `m_print` is not a function. `m_print<int>` is a function. Hence it is not entirely clear what you want to do.

You can declare a variable template:

```
template <typename T> constexpr auto func_ptr = &m_print<T>;
```

And you can declare a function pointer to some instantiation of `m_print`. For example for `m_print<int>` :

```
auto func_ptr = &m_print<int>;
```

Perhaps you do not need a function pointer. If you just want some entity that can be passed around that instantiates the function only when called you can use a lambda with `auto` parameter:

```
auto func = [](auto x){ m_print(x); };
```

This results in a function object with a templated call operator. `func(42)` will call `m_print<int>` while `func(4.2)` will call `m_print<double>`.